# Pyqt5 WebEngineWidgets Requested OpenGL implementation is not supported. Implementation

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

When I run this code in `pyqt5`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

I get this error:

```
[5436:7020:0612/202711.692:ERROR:gl_surface_wgl.cc(399)] Unable to create pbuffer.
[5436:7020:0612/202711.692:ERROR:gl_surface_qt.cpp(197)] Requested OpenGL implementation is not supported. Implementation: 1
```

What is the reason?

Comment: please edit your question so the code part of it will look like code

Comment: try add `app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL, True)` after  `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: also add `import os` `os.environ["QT_WEBENGINE_DISABLE_GPU"] = "1"` before  `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`